# React JS fetch data from multiple API function

Tags: reactjs, rest, fetch-api

I was tasked to create a front-end for a poc. I am not a front end developer but I chose to use React JS.
There is only one page fetching data from multiple API endpoints. API endpoints return a simple json object.
I managed to get that to work however my code is ugly af and I want to create a function to handle all of that but I can't seem to get it right. Here's my code

```
export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      group1: [],
      group2: [],
      group3: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    }
  }

componentDidMount() {
    const group1_url = "http://localhost/api/1"
    const group2_url = "http://localhost/api/2"
    const group3_url = "http://localhost/api/3"

    fetch(group1_url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          group1: json,
        })
      });
    fetch(group2_url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          group2: json,
        })
      });
    fetch(group3_url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          group3: json,
        })
      });
  }
```

I am trying to create a function like this:

```
 function fetch_data(url, state) {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          state: json,
        })
      });
  }

var group1 = fetch_data(group1_url, group1);
```

So far no joy. How can I create a function to fetch data and set a state in js?
Alternatively how can I make my code look better? Or is there something else I should use/look into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a *string* as the second parameter, and use a computed property:

```
function fetch_data(url, state) {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          [state]: json,
        })
      });
  }

fetch_data(group1_url, 'group1');
```

I'd also highly recommend catching errors - possible unhandled rejections should be avoided whenever possible.

You might want to use `Promise.all` to wait for all groups to load:

```
const dataSources = {
    group1: 'http://localhost/api/1',
    group2: 'http://localhost/api/2',
    group3: 'http://localhost/api/3',
};
```

```
Promise.all(
    Object.entries(dataSources).map(([propertyName, url]) => (
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                this.setState({
                    [propertyName]: result
                })
            })
    ))
)
    .then(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoaded: true })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // handle errors
    })
```

(also note that [your `json` argument is not a JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) - JSON is only a format that exists with *strings*. Something that has been deserialized is just a plain object or array. Better to call it something less misleading, like `result` as I did)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used your implementation in my code and it worked straight away. It is much cleaner now. I added error handling too.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Promise.all](https://javascript.info/promise-api#promise-all)

> Promise.all takes an array of promises (it technically can be any iterable, but is usually an array) and returns a new promise.

```
const points = [
    "http://localhost/api/1",
    "http://localhost/api/2",
    "http://localhost/api/3",
];

const responses = await Promise.all(points.map((point) => fetch(point)));
const data = await Promise.all(responses.map((response) => response.json()));
const [group1, group2, group3] = data;

this.setState({
    group1,
    group2,
    group3,
});
```

Just remember to wrap this logic in an [async](https://javascript.info/async-await) function

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
function fetch_data(url, state) {
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({
      [state]: json,
    })
  });
}

var group1 = fetch_data(group1_url, 'group1');
```